# Maptiler using OSM and Satellite tiles at the same time

Tags: openstreetmap, mbtiles, satellite-image, maptiler

I have downloaded and setup the maptiler server on Docker on my machine. I bought a subscription and have downloaded the OSM maps and it seems to work just fine. However I see there are satellite maps I would like to use as well. Is this possible. Do I need to run a second server with the Satellite files or can they co-exist same server and how would I choose/switch between them.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Not related to programming. Did you try asking at https://support.maptiler.com/?

Comment: I checked but all support is chargeable. I am seeking some help or advice on configuration settings.... If its not appropriate question here then many apologies. The maptiler support site recommends asking questions here..

Comment: Try asking at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.